# Echarts align tooltip with different xAxis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts, apache-echarts

I'm using the Echarts library for React and I'm stuck on this problem.
I have two charts with this data:

- x: array of Date
- y: array of numbers

They are plotted and connected using the [connect API](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts.connect): in this way, the mouseover event on the two charts is synchronized based on the xAxis value, and the tooltips are shown. It happens that on the same x value, the two dates are different, thus the 2 tooltips show different dates. How can I synchronize them using the x value (the date) instead of the coordinate?

Thanks